# Kafka streams listener does not receive assignment, but spring KafkaListener does

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application with

1. Spring Kafka listener, listening to topic1
2. Class with defined KafkaStreams instance, with own application.id app-id-1, listening to topic2, producing messages to topic2-inner. app-id-1 was implement by KafkaStreams DSL
   topic1, topic2 and topic2-inner has only 1 partition.
   Everything worked well.

I need implement new KafkaStreams instance with localStore and Punctuator, so I implemented it by Processor API. I create new Topology() etc., set another application.id app-id-2.
This new streams instance must listen topic1 in parallel with first Kafka listener.
But this new streams instance does not receive messages from topic1, but listener does.
In logs I see, that new KafkaStreams app-id-2 does not receive assignment from broker.
Is this my configuration mistake, or Kafka broker error?
How I should configurate new streams application?
Any help appreciated)

SpringBoot 2.7.3
java 17
Kakfa streams 3.1.0

application.yaml:

```
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 'kafka1, kafka2'
    listener:
      concurrency: 3
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      isolation-level: read_committed
      properties:
        partition.assignment.strategy: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.StickyAssignor
    streams:
      application-id: app-id-1
      properties:
        bootstrap.servers: 'kafka1, kafka2'
        commit.interval.ms: 100
        metrics.recording.level: TRACE
        auto.offset.reset: latest
```

Listener:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic1", groupId = "group1", autoStartup = "true")
    public void receive(@Payload String message,
                                  @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) String messageTimestamp,
                                  @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        log.info("Listener start message processing");
}
```

KafkaStreams instance app-id-1:

```
private final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder;
private final KafkaStreamsConfiguration configuration;
private final UncaughtExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    @PostConstruct
    private void startStream() {
        streamsBuilder.stream("topic2", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .peek(($, message) -> log(message))               
                .to("topic2-inner", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), configuration.asProperties());
        streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
        streams.start();
    }
```

KafkaStreams instance app-id-2:

Processor

```
  public LastPriceProcessor(String stateStoreName, Duration duration, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.stateStoreName = stateStoreName;
    this.pauseDuration = duration;
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
  }

  @Override
  public void init(ProcessorContext<String, PriceStore> context) {
    log.info("Processor initiated");
    super.init(context);
    keyValueStore = context().getStateStore(stateStoreName);
    Punctuator punctuator = new Punctuator((org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext) context(),
        keyValueStore);
    context().schedule(pauseDuration, PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, punctuator);
  }

  @Override
  public void process(Record<String, String> record) {
    log.info("LastPriceProcessor start process");
}
```

Stream starting service:

```
private final KafkaStreamsConfiguration configuration;
private final KafkaStreamsProperties kafkaStreamsProperties;



  @PostConstruct
  private void startStream() {
Topology topology = new Topology();

    KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(PRICE_STORE);
    Serializer<PriceStore> priceStoreSerializer = new PriceStoreSerializer(objectMapper);
    Deserializer<PriceStore> priceStoreDeserializer = new PriceStoreSerializer(objectMapper);
    StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, PriceStore>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(storeSupplier,
        Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(priceStoreSerializer, priceStoreDeserializer));

    String destinationTopic = "topic4";

    topology.addSource("price-source",
        Serdes.String().deserializer(),
        Serdes.String().deserializer(),
        "topic1")
        .addProcessor("processor-name",
            () -> new Processor("store-name", kafkaStreamsProperties, objectMapper),
            "price-source")
        .addStateStore(storeBuilder, "processor-name")
        .addSink("sink-name", destinationTopic, Serdes.String().serializer(), priceStoreSerializer, "processor-name");

    StreamsConfig streamsConfig = new StreamsConfig(getProperties());
    KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(topology, streamsConfig);
    kafkaStreams.start();
}

  private Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = configuration.asProperties();
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app-id-2");
    return properties;
  }
```